# How can I make a duplicate of a table row in mysql?

Tags: mysql

This is my table `farm`:

```
+--------+
| animal |
+--------+
| cat    |
| monkey |
| bird   |
| dog    |
| horse  |
+--------+
```

I want to make an exact duplicate of the row `animal`. So my table should look like this:

```
+--------+---------+
| animal | animal2 |
+--------+---------+
| cat    | cat     |
| monkey | monkey  |
| bird   | bird    |
| dog    | dog     |
| horse  | horse   |
+--------+---------+
```

I tried

```
INSERT INTO `farm` (`animal2`) SELECT `animal` FROM `animals`
```

But what happens is this:

```
+--------+---------+
| animal | animal2 |
+--------+---------+
| cat    |         |
| monkey |         |
| bird   |         |
| dog    |         |
| horse  |         |
|        | cat     |
|        | monkey  |
|        | bird    |
|        | dog     |
|        | horse   |
+--------+---------+
```

Comment: what is the table definition of farm? is there primary key?

Comment: You need to create new column using `ALTER TABLE farm ADD animal2 VARCHAR(100)` and then update it `UPDATE farm SET animal2 = animal`

Comment: @Dylan Su no, I do not have a primary key for this table

Comment: @lad2025 could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should add new column (with the same datatype) and `NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE `farm` ADD `animal2` VARCHAR(100);
```

Then simply update:

```
UPDATE `farm` SET `animal2` = `animal`;
```

If you need `NOT NULL` property alter table once again with `NOT NULL`.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/448886)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════╦═════════╗
║ animal ║ animal2 ║
╠════════╬═════════╣
║ cat    ║ cat     ║
║ monkey ║ monkey  ║
║ bird   ║ bird    ║
║ dog    ║ dog     ║
║ horse  ║ horse   ║
╚════════╩═════════╝
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid deleting unrelated data in table, use the following method.

```
DELETE FROM `farm` WHERE `animal1` IN (SELECT `animal` FROM `animals`);
INSERT INTO `farm` (`animal`, `animal2`) SELECT `animal`, `animal` FROM `animals`;
```

Comment: This worked but deleted all my other rows in the table :(

Comment: no, something still must be wrong. I tried now to use `UPDATE `farm` SET `animal2` = `animal`;` and it works very well